# What is the name of this font don't recognized by others tools

Tags: text, font-identification, black

[image: D&S]

The letters are D&S.

In fact, other tools don't recognize this letters because I think the letters are black with dark background.

This come from a photo of a flyer of my client: D&S Esthetic, Center of Aesthetic.

Comment: Try manipulating the image to isolate the letters before uploading to a font finder.

Comment: I isolate the letters with a graphic program, and effectively I find the same font as Romanesco.

Answer (score 1):

There you go:
https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Romanesco
It's called ROMANESCO.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. While this may indeed be the font, can you please [edit your answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/156820/edit) and add a screen shot of the font. Link only answers are usually discouraged here since links are prone to rot. Thanks.